# Single item in Wagtail StreamField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, wagtail

How do I create a dynamic content block on a Page model. Let's say I want a block representing a google map. So, I aggregate this StructBlock as the zoom level, lat, and lng with the template rendering the block.

The idea is to avoid user's actually having to enter lat / lng in the admin and just use the search maps provides and set the lat / lng dynamically this way.

The only way I know of to add this is wrapping the block in `StreamField` then adding ti as a stream field panel.

However, this allows multiple to be added when I only want one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using StreamFields and StructBlocks, you can define the `min_num` and/or `max_num` of how many of those blocks you want the user to be able to create. See [StructBlock docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/streamfield.html#streamblock).

Example:

```
class MyPage(Page):
    map = StreamField(
        MapBlock(max_num=1, min_num=1, required=True)
    )
```

This feature was added in [1.12](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/releases/1.12.html#other-features).